# Database query select where most recent date - MAX not working

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

I would like to select last inserted data in my table.

I tried :

```
Source = "SELECT * FROM HistoSpreadLiq WHERE DateSpread=MAX(DateSpread)"
```

But this doesn't work -> returns : Error Automation..

`MAX(DateSpread)` should `return 04/11/2020`

DateSpread is a date format in my AccessDB

And when I hard code:

```
Source = "SELECT * FROM HistoSpreadLiq WHERE DateSpread=04/11/2020"
```

It does work, what am I missing?

Please note that I execute this SQL request in Excel and my database is an Access database (.accdb)

Comment: Try surrounding the field with [  DateSpread ] brackets

Comment: @RicardoDiaz that won't work `MAX(DateSpread)` needs a `select`. See the linke above the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then answer was that I had to do an other select :

```
"SELECT * FROM HistoSpreadLiq WHERE DateSpread=(SELECT Max(DateSpread) FROM HistoSpreadLiq)"
```